# Cordova error when adding android platform

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant

I'm trying to add the android platform using this command "platform add android error" but I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/C3ShDqn.png

My user folder is "C:\Users\Cretu Eusebiu" but in that error it's says only "C:\Users\Cretu" so I guess is something wrong with the space ?

I've set all paths for npm, android, ant and java.

Thank you.

Comment: I have had problems with ' ' (space character) and the CLI before. I have not figured out a solution other than not using paths that contain spaces.

Comment: A wild guess is that the script that is running is not expecting paths with spaces and thus hasn't quoted it properly. This is probably an error in the scripts used by cordova... As for solving it.. New user without space in the account name? Or finding the script and properly quoting input.

Comment: I've created a new user (without spaces) and everything works fine. So it's something with the Cordova module.

Answer (score 2):

It was not because of my username with spaces, it was from the spaces of the path where I created the app "C:\Google Drive\Android Apps".